# Using a while loop to take in a string of numbers and then returning the average

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Hello I am writing a program that wants me to take in a user input and return the average of the input the user has to enter (0) to stop the program. My issues come in the incriminating the user numbers, I cant seem to get it to add the numbers in the array together.

Here is the code..

```
public class Week2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments

     */
    public static void main(String[] args){

        // TODO code application logic here 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    int sum = 0;
    System.out.println("Input some postive integers (0) to stop."); 
    n = input.nextInt();
    while (n != 0) { // while loop
    System.out.println("Please enter (0) to stop"); 
    sum = sum + n;
    n = input.nextInt();
```

the sum = sum + n; is the variable I want to use to add up the numbers but when I run the program and hit 0 it just says hit (0) to stop for every user imputed number.

Comment: The code seems ok. Can you add the last bit as well?

Answer (score 1):

I added a close brace and a print statement after your loop,

```
while (n != 0) { // while loop
  System.out.println("Please enter (0) to stop");
  sum = sum + n;
  n = input.nextInt();
} // <-- here
System.out.printf("The sum is %d%n", sum);
```

And it works here.